# Run stored procedure from where it failed last in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have written a stored procedure in BigQuery that calls multiple (other) stored procedures one after the other. If the last procedure fails, I have to re-run the entire procedure again from the beginning.

Is there a way, I can run the procedure from the last point it failed. The format of my stored procedure looks something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `dataset.procedure_name` ()
BEGIN
    CALL `dataset.procedure1`();
    CALL `dataset.procedure2`();
    CALL `dataset.procedure3`();
    CALL `dataset.procedure4`();
    CALL `dataset.procedure5`();
END
```

Comment: I think currently there is no way to do that natively in bigquery with SQL. I would recommend to use other services along with bigquery to queue, manage and orchestrate your data pipelines/transformations like dataflow, cloud functions or cloud composer.

Comment: how do you know which have failed? and which to skip next time?

Comment: How about using a table for checkpoint ? you can insert the state of finished procedures into the checkpoint table and later resume the procedures based on the information on the checkpoint table.

Comment: You could setup your own control table like @Jaytiger is suggesting but I would recommend you install GCP Composer (Airflow) and setup dags to manage this.